# How to resolve a Null Web service Response using Retrofit2?

Tags: android, json, web-services, parsing, retrofit2

My JSON response that I need to parse using Retrofit2**

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0062,
    "cnt": 4,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1531915200,
            "main": {
                "temp": 308,
                "temp_min": 307.876,
                "temp_max": 308,
                "pressure": 1013.67,
                "sea_level": 1028.96,
                "grnd_level": 1013.67,
                "humidity": 32,
                "temp_kf": 0.13
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "clear sky",
                    "icon": "01d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 0
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 1.96,
                "deg": 90.0012
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2018-07-18 12:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1531926000,
            "main": {
                "temp": 309.55,
                "temp_min": 309.452,
                "temp_max": 309.55,
                "pressure": 1012.51,
                "sea_level": 1027.69,
                "grnd_level": 1012.51,
                "humidity": 30,
                "temp_kf": 0.09
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "clear sky",
                    "icon": "01d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 0
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 2.63,
                "deg": 72.5014
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2018-07-18 15:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1531936800,
            "main": {
                "temp": 306.87,
                "temp_min": 306.808,
                "temp_max": 306.87,
                "pressure": 1012.06,
                "sea_level": 1027.49,
                "grnd_level": 1012.06,
                "humidity": 32,
                "temp_kf": 0.06
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "clear sky",
                    "icon": "01d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 0
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 2.42,
                "deg": 68.0013
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2018-07-18 18:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1531947600,
            "main": {
                "temp": 297.77,
                "temp_min": 297.738,
                "temp_max": 297.77,
                "pressure": 1012.84,
                "sea_level": 1028.22,
                "grnd_level": 1012.84,
                "humidity": 59,
                "temp_kf": 0.03
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 801,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "few clouds",
                    "icon": "02n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 24
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 2.32,
                "deg": 120.5
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2018-07-18 21:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "city": {
        "id": 2464470,
        "name": "Tunis",
        "coord": {
            "lat": 36.8001,
            "lon": 10.1848
        },
        "country": "TN",
        "population": 693210
    }
}
```

**My Java class "WeatherResponse" that instantiates the response object:**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;



public class WeatherResponse {

    @SerializedName("cod")
    private String cod;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private double message;

    @SerializedName("cnt")
    private double cnt;
   @SerializedName("list")
    private java.util.List<List> list =null;

    public java.util.List<List> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

**My line of code where I assign the response body:**

```
WeatherResponse wD = response.body();
```

**The response I get** :

[image]

Comment: from the image, your `response body` is not null, click on the arrow to the left of `body`

Comment: I've edited the image , You can check it now, The problem is I only get one correct attribute which is the "cod" element , I don't understand why my "list" element is null

Comment: share  `List.java`

Comment: public class List {


    private Main main;

    private java.util.List<Weather> weather = null;

    private String dtTxt;


    public Main getMain() {
        return main;
    }


    public java.util.List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public String getDtTxt() {
        return dtTxt;
    }


}

Comment: and this is "Main" class used to display "main" weather temperature-->
public class Main {

    private Double temp;


    public Double getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }



}

Comment: use `@SerializedName` for fields

Comment: I tried that , :( it didnt work would you please provide me your email so i can send you the whole project ? Or I can share the project on Google Drive ..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14fvX3LYeQKrS4K44mJK1u9f6lQK9DN0D   there y'a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `WeatherResponse.java` change

change

```
@SerializedName("list")
private java.util.List<List> list =null;
```

to

```
@SerializedName("weather")
private java.util.List<Weather> list =null;
```

**`WeatherResponse.java`**

```
public class WeatherResponse {

    @SerializedName("cod")
    private String cod;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private double message;

    @SerializedName("cnt")
    private int cnt;

    @SerializedName("weather")
    private java.util.List<Weather> list =null;


    public java.util.List<Weather> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

**`Weather.java`**

```
    public class Weather {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private String main;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getMain() {
return main;
}

public void setMain(String main) {
this.main = main;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public String getIcon() {
return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
this.icon = icon;
}

}
```

Comment: I get the same null response.

Comment: see edited answer change like this `@SerializedName("weather")
private java.util.List<Weather> list =null;`

Comment: Wow you are a true genius! it worked but I have one final question .. why you didn't define  "list": [ ] element in WeatherResponse  Class .. xD

Comment: And how did you access "weather" array  without defining the "list" element

Comment: Because there is no element named as list in your response, also please accept the answer if working

Comment: You might have mistyped weather as list